# Aquery load image from file with rounded corners

Tags: android, aquery

I am trying to load an image from file in an ImageView using Aquery. As mentioned in [docs](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading), I can load image from url with rounded corners by applying ImageOptions. But there is no method in which I can pass both file and ImageOptions. Hence, I am unable to get rounded corners on ImageView from local file. Any idea how to acheive this?